# Django - retrieve form data

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to send a form through ajax call to django view as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{% url 'edit_experience' %}",
            data: {
                  item_id : itemId,
                  form: $("#sample-form").serialize()
            },
            beforeSend : function() {

            },
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function(data) {

            },
            complete : function() {

            }
});
```

I am able to see the data being posted to the http server:

```
form    role=Fresher&organization=TestOrganization&description=Hard+work+pays
item_id 3
```

My problem is in the server side where I am trying to fetch the data. I am able to access the `item_id` but I am having a problem accessing the form elements:

In Django View:

```
def edit_experience(request):
     request.POST['form']['role']
     return ....
```

This does not fetch the role. What is the correct way to fetch all the form attributes??

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch attributes from the querystring you can use [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict):

```
from django.http import QueryDict
d = QueryDict(request.POST['form'])
role = d['role']
```